# Computer vision image masking issue

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

Can any one please help me with this. When i use this function it works for red and yellow signal images but not for green. Green signal images are all black. Any idea what’s wrong. But surprisingly if i make it `BGR2HSV` it shows green signal images but other 2 are black. I’m using `Matplotlib` to import images so i guess it’s `RGB` by default.

**def mask(rgb_image) :**

```
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

## mask of red color range 1
red_mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, (0,20,0), (10,255,255))

## mask of red color range 2
red_mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, (170,20,0), (180,255,255))

## mask of green
green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, (40,0,0), (80,255,255))

## mask of yellow
yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, (10,30,100), (30,255,255))

## final mask
mask1 = cv2.bitwise_or(red_mask1, red_mask2)
mask2 = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, yellow_mask)
mask3 = cv2.bitwise_or(mask2, green_mask)

target = cv2.bitwise_and(rgb_image,rgb_image, mask=mask3)

plt.imshow(target)
```

**Code used to read image:**

```
def load_dataset(image_dir):

    im_list = []
    image_types = ["red", "yellow", "green"]

    for im_type in image_types:
      for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(image_dir, im_type, "*")):
        im = mpimg.imread(file) 
        if not im is None:
            im_list.append((im, im_type))
    return im_list
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use to read in images?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

It worked: My range for green was incorrect. It should be Lower: (80,20,20), Upper:(170,255,255).